# Error activating Addon | Rotation Settings in Panel

Tags: python

i have tried everything to get this running, and it is, kinda.

So - what this script do:

It export wireframes from 3D models with 1 button click.
That works fine, but i want the rotations settings over the button : do the Wireframe (img attached)

[image]

Also i want to disable the other tabs - except of the 3D Wireframe tab.

My biggest problem is the activating from the Addon, error attached in image:

[image]

my script:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "3D Wireframe",
    "author": "Design Gecko",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 7, 9),
    "location": "View3D > Tool Shelf > 3D Wireframe by Design Gecko",
    "description": "Converts any object in a 3D Wireframe for Laser Engraving",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
    }
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

import os
import bpy
from pathlib import Path
from sys import platform
from bpy import context

def main(context):

    #combine Object

    for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if ob.type == 'MESH':
            ob.select = True
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
        else:
            ob.select = False
    bpy.ops.object.join()


    #set size to camera
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set( type = 'ORIGIN_GEOMETRY' )
    bpy.ops.object.location_clear()



    #ADJUST ANGLE
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = 8



    # Select objects that will be rendered
    for obj in scene.objects:
        obj.select = False
    for obj in context.visible_objects:
        if not (obj.hide or obj.hide_render):
            obj.select = True

    bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()



    #Deleting all materials
    for material in bpy.data.materials:
        material.user_clear()
        bpy.data.materials.remove(material)




    # this is the new center of the camera view


    for obj in scene.objects:
        obj.select = False
    for obj in context.visible_objects:
        if not (obj.hide or obj.hide_render):
            obj.select = True

    bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()

    #Resolution 100%
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100

    #Compression 0%
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.compression = 0

    #Checkbox Freestyle Edge true
    bpy.context.scene.render.use_freestyle = True

    #Check Freestyle to SVG Export true
    bpy.context.scene.svg_export.use_svg_export = True

    freestyle_settings = bpy.context.scene.render.layers["RenderLayer"].freestyle_settings

    lineset = freestyle_settings.linesets["LineSet"]

    lineset.select_edge_mark = True


    #Set background Color to White
    bpy.context.scene.world.ambient_color = (1, 1, 1)


    #Editmode
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()


    #Mark Freestyle Edge
    bpy.ops.mesh.mark_freestyle_edge(clear=False)

    #Back to object mode
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()


    #Render and Export on Desktop

    home_dir = str(Path.home())

    if platform == 'linux' or platform == 'win32' or platform == 'darwin':
        desktop_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, 'Desktop')
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("OS not supported")

    if bpy.app.version < (2, 80, 00):
        filename_prefix = bpy.context.scene.objects.active.name
    else:
        filename_prefix = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.name

    output = os.path.join(desktop_dir, filename_prefix)
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output

    bpy.ops.render.render()

class Wireframe3D(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.wireframe_3d"
    bl_label = "Do my Wireframe"


    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Wireframe3DPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Tool Shelf"""
    bl_label = "3D Wireframe Converter by Design Gecko"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_designgecko"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "3D Wireframe by Design Gecko"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.wireframe_3d")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Wireframe3D)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Wireframe3DPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Wireframe3D)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Wireframe3DPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    scene = context.scene

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.object.wireframe_3d()
```

New Error while activating:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that the error is in line 47 which is:

```
for obj in scene.objects:
```

You haven't declared and assigned a variable named `scene`, so the correct code would be:

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
```

The same mistake happens in line 68 as well. Alternatively you can also create a variable named `scene` and assign `bpy.context.scene` to it.

---

In order to add the object's rotation property to the panel, you can use add the following code to the `draw()` function of the `Wireframe3DPanel`:

```
row = layout.row()
row.prop(obj, "rotation_euler")
```

Comment: Changed the Line but the error is the same :( the error changed i think, iw ill attach new image

Comment: Because you've made the same mistake twice. There is another line where you try to access the scene in the same way.

Comment: Also changed the second line to the code u told me, but i think this its a different error then this one when activating.

Comment: ITS WORKING THANK YOU, forgot the line on 20, which you cant see becs in this script it isnt :D Do you know the reason for the Rotation thing as well :D?